# Place image before div using :before

Tags: html, css, image, background

I'm trying to place an image before and after `div` using `:before` and `:after`.
Unfortunately, I don't see images. Why?

Here is the code (and in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u234x/)):

```
<div style="border:1px solid green; padding:50px;">
  <div id="videos-part">test</div>
</div>

#videos-part{

    height: 127px;
    width: 764px;
border:1px solid red;
    margin:30px;
    padding:30px;
}
#videos-part:before{
    width: 46px;
    height:46px;
    content: "before ";
    background-image: url(http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/136059938344542682.png);

}
#videos-part:after{
    width: 46px;
    height:46px;
    content: " after";
    background-image: url(http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/136059938344542682.png);

}
```

Comment: check the images. i have applied different images and it is showing

Comment: The problem doesn't come from the code, you wrote it right, the issue comes from the image urls check this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/u234x/9/

Comment: I tested your fiddle in FF and IE and it seems to work fine, but I do see a delay when downloading the icon from iconpedia.net.  This problem may not be an issue if you load the icons directly from your hosting server.  You have some styling issues, for example, you may want to set `display: inline-block` to the pseudo-elements and the icon dimensions are 64x64, unless you rescale the background image (cover or something like that).

Answer (score 5):

Using `pseudo element` you can add images and custom icon and create custom shapes as well.  Check the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/u234x/5/)** first.

```
#videos-part{
    height: 127px;
    width: 764px;
border:1px solid red;
    margin:30px;
    padding:30px;
}
#videos-part:before{
    width: 46px;
    height:46px;
    content: " ";
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:30px;
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50/");

}
#videos-part:after{
    width: 46px;
    height:46px;
    content: " ";
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:60px;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x50");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply this syntax:

`content: url(imageURL);` with no `background-image`.

CSS:

```
#videos-part{

    height: 127px;
    width: 764px;
border:1px solid red;
    margin:30px;
    padding:30px;
}
#videos-part:before{
    width: 46px;
    height:46px;
    content: url(http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/136059938344542682.png);
}
#videos-part:after{
    width: 46px;
    height:46px;
    content: url(http://aux.iconpedia.net/uploads/136059938344542682.png);

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u234x/)

Comment: you jsfiddle is the same as the one the op posted

Comment: @vlrprbttst This works the issue is the image urls : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/u234x/11/

Comment: This is actually a valid solution, in fact, you don't need to set the width and height of the pseudo-elements.  See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8qfM9/  However, the background-image approach also works.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:inline-block` to `#videos-part` before and after selectors.

```
#videos-part:after, #videos-part:before {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u234x/6/) here.

Comment: so what is the difference??

Answer (score 1):

here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/u234x/7/

1) the urls of your images are wrong (i've put a placeholder)
2) `content` must stay empty
3) you may need to apply `relative` to the parent `div` and `absolute` to the pseudo elements `:before` and `:after` and place them using `top`/`bottom` `left`/`right` values